# Passing null parameter from VFP to .NET Com Class

Tags: c#, com, null, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have class in .NET and calling this class as a COM object from foxpro.
This class has methods which can accept different class type as a parameter.
How can I pass NULL to .NET class method?

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ProgId("ParameterClass")]
[ComVisible(true)]
class ParameterClass
{
    public ParameterClass f_ClassMethod_2(ParameterClass _d) 
    {
        Debugger.Launch();
        return _d;
    }
}
```

Creating object in VFP:

```
cls= CREATEOBJECT("ParameterClass ")
```

This code returns error:

```
obj3 = cls.f_ClassMethod_2(null) 
//Error: OLE error code 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
```

or this code:

```
obj3 = cls.f_ClassMethod_2(.Null.) 
//Error: OLE error code 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
```

or this code:

```
prm = .Null.
obj3 = cls.f_ClassMethod_2(prm) 
//Error: OLE error code 0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having problems with the NULL interpretation between them, I would try an extra method in your VB such as.. then call your method directly from within itself

```
  public ParameterClass f_ClassMethodAsNULL() 
    {
        f_ClassMethod_2( null );
        ... etc...
    }
```

Then, you should just be able to call the function f_ClassMethodAsNULL() from VFP